# Why isn't calldata used in this function's argument? (OpenZeppelin/OwnableUpgradeable.sol)

Tags: solidity, gas-price, solidity-0.8.x, calldata, function

Solidity noob here; reading about data locations i've learned that whenever you don't need to store or modify a function's input value it's actually more gas efficient to set its location to calldata (oversimplifying the concept).
That said, i've came across a function into "OwnableUpgradeable.sol" by OpenZeppelin (but i've seen this in other instances) that doesn't set an argument's location to calldata even though its value will not be altered. Why is that? I know i'm missing something but i cannot understand what.

---

[image: OpenZeppelin case]

---

[image: Another case from github]

---
Can anyone explain or link to an explanation of why it's not correct to set these two arguments' locations to calldata?

Answer (score 0):

Because calldata is for arrays not primitive types like strings or addresses.